# How to find position of character in a string multiple times in python?

Tags: python, string, indexing

```
for item in s:
    if item == "r":
        s = list(s)
        posR = s.index("r")
        while s[posR-1] == "a" or s[posR-1] == "e"\
           or  s[posR-1] == "i" or s[posR-1] == "o"\
           or s[posR-1] == "u":
            s[posR-1] = ""
```

In the code above, the program checks if the letter "r" is in a string (represented in the variable 's' and if it is r, then checks if the letter before this r is a vowel, and if it is the vowel is removed.
e.g.

```
s = iterate
s = itrate
```

But how do I make the program do this if there are multiple 'r's in the string?
i.e.

```
s = characters
s = chractrs
```

Comment: @Shashank: agree, seconded.

Comment: Do you want `'beer'` to become `'ber'` or `'br'` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

s = 'iterater'
re.sub('[aeiou]r', 'r', s)
```